# I'm trying to make a responsive menu using css grid-area. Is there a way I can make all other divs fade when one is hovered, not just those after?

Tags: html, css

I want it so that all other grids in the grid-area fade to 0.3 opacity, but only those after in the html will fade when one is hovered over. I was wondering if anybody knew how to fix this?

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .item1 { grid-area: header; }
        .item2 { grid-area: menu; }
        .item3 { grid-area: main; }
        .item4 { grid-area: right; }
        .item5 { grid-area: footer; }

         .grid-container {
             margin-left: 12.5%;
             display: grid;
             width: 75%;
             grid-template-areas:
                 'header header'
                 'menu right'
                 'main footer';
             grid-gap: 60px;
             padding: 10px;
         }
         .grid-container > div {
             background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
             text-align: center;
             padding: 20px 0;
             font-size: 30px;
             border-radius: 25px;
             background: #ffffff;
             transition: 2s;
         }
         .grid-container > div:hover {
             opacity: 1;
             padding: 50px;
         }
         .grid-container > div:hover ~ [class^="item"] {
             opacity: 0.3;
         }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="item1">Header</div>
        <div class="item2" id="item2">menu</div>
        <div class="item3" id="item3">main</div>  
        <div class="item4" id="item4">right</div>
        <div class="item5" id="item5">Footer</div>
      </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You could set `.grid-container:hover>div {opacity:0.3}` and `.grid-container>div:hover {opacity:1}`.

Comment: That's great and does near enough what I want!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, this should work for you:

```
.grid-container:hover > div {
    opacity: 0.3;
}

.grid-container > div:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    padding: 50px;
}
```